# Cannot get email body in IMAP from Gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I want to read GMail's email body.

I am able to get all details like fromname, email and subject etc but not Email body.

```
// Connect to gmail
$username = 'email';
$password = 'password';
/* connect to server */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if ($emails) {
    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';
    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);
    /* for every email... */
    foreach ($emails as $email_number) {
        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "1.2");

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler ' . ($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread') . '">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">' . $overview[0]->subject . '</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">' . $overview[0]->from . '</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on ' . $overview[0]->date . '</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">' . $message . '</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

I know there is specific Gmail's API for doing that but shouldn't IMAP work?

From PHP's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php) it says

```
(empty) - Entire message
0 - Message header
1 - MULTIPART/ALTERNATIVE
1.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
1.2 - TEXT/HTML
2 - MESSAGE/RFC822 (entire attached message)
2.0 - Attached message header
2.1 - TEXT/PLAIN
2.2 - TEXT/HTML
2.3 - file.ext
```

I have tried `$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "1.2");` and `$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 1.2);`

But it returns empty results.

I also tried `$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, "2");` but it returns broken HTML very different from the one I get in Gmail.

Comment: That is a sample body structure, you need to find what YOUR email's bodystructure is.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'Broken HTML'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alight I had to use

`$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, 2));`

to get the message right.

Comment: Thank you, with Max' and your input I figured it out too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and succeeded

```
$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($conn, $email_number, 1));
```